# Converting list of dictionary and dictionay data to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to send a SOAP request and iteratively and the response captured for each iteration is as follows.

```
df = {
   '@diffgr:id': 'Table1', 
   '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 
   'NVIC_CUR': '0BQU22', 
   'NVIC_MODEL': '0BQU', 
   'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'
}

{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '0BQT22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '0BQT', 'ModelName': 'FDIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'}
[{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '09GE22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '09GE', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'}, {'@diffgr:id': 'Table2', '@msdata:rowOrder': '1', 'NVIC_CUR': '0BR222', 'NVIC_MODEL': '0BR2', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'}]
[{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '09HR22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '09HR', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP AUTOMATIC'}, {'@diffgr:id': 'Table2', '@msdata:rowOrder': '1', 'NVIC_CUR': '09HS22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '09HS', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP MANUAL'}]
```

The SOAP API sometimes return dictionary data, and sometime list of dictionary.

My idea was to create a Dataframe of selected columns (NVIC_CUR, NVIC_MODEL, ModelName)

[output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ec0l.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to convert df into a DataFrame

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **pandas** library, it makes it quite easy:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {
   '@diffgr:id': 'Table1', 
   '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 
   'NVIC_CUR': '0BQU22', 
   'NVIC_MODEL': '0BQU', 
   'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'
}

if isinstance(df, list):
    result = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['NVIC_CUR', 'NVIC_MODEL', 'ModelName'])
else:
    result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, 
                                    orient='index',
                                    columns=['NVIC_CUR', 'NVIC_MODEL', 'ModelName']
                                    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SLDem. much appreciated. I modified it while working on it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this three-step-

1. You can append each `SOAP` API response to either its `dictionary` or a `list` to a new python `list`, let's say its called - **list_of_dict**, and
2. Then iterate it and append it to a new `list` let's call it **final_list_of_dict** if it's a `dictionary` else iterate it again if a `list`like below.
3. Finally, make a dataframe from the list of dictionaries.

**Fullcode:**

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dict = [{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '0BQU22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '0BQU', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'},
{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '0BQT22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '0BQT', 'ModelName': 'FDIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'},
[{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '09GE22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '09GE', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'}, {'@diffgr:id': 'Table2', '@msdata:rowOrder': '1', 'NVIC_CUR': '0BR222', 'NVIC_MODEL': '0BR2', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC'}],
[{'@diffgr:id': 'Table1', '@msdata:rowOrder': '0', 'NVIC_CUR': '09HR22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '09HR', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP AUTOMATIC'}, {'@diffgr:id': 'Table2', '@msdata:rowOrder': '1', 'NVIC_CUR': '09HS22', 'NVIC_MODEL': '09HS', 'ModelName': 'DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP MANUAL'}]
]

final_list_of_dict = []
for item in list_of_dict:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for item in item:
            final_list_of_dict.append(item)
    final_list_of_dict.append(item)    
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list_of_dict, columns=['NVIC_CUR', 'NVIC_MODEL','ModelName'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  NVIC_CUR NVIC_MODEL                                          ModelName
0   0BQU22       0BQU  DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC
1   0BQT22       0BQT  FDIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOM...
2   09GE22       09GE  DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC
3   0BR222       0BR2  DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC
4   0BR222       0BR2  DIESEL TWIN TURBO 4 1996 cc BTCDI 10 SP AUTOMATIC
5   09HR22       09HR         DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP AUTOMATIC
6   09HS22       09HS            DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP MANUAL
7   09HS22       09HS            DIESEL TURBO 5 3198 cc DTFI 6 SP MANUAL
```

Comment: Thank you @Always Sunny, much appreciated. Worked absolutely fine :)

Comment: @RajeshArtist glad it helps you somehow, btw: you accepted another answer, is there any issue with my solution? because I think I explain it better that that solution on my answer :)